# Azure Static WebSite not loading supported js files

Tags: angular, azure, azure-blob-storage

I just created a Static WebSite at Azure portal that gave me url like https://abcd.z99.web.core.windows.net/ but when I upload files and navigate to this url it loads index.html page with below error.

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a
>   non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is
>   enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

I get this for runtime-XXX, polifiles-XXX, and main-XXX files.

What Am I missing here?

Comment: is this angular app?

Comment: Yes It is, Angular 9 App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is mentioned in the [`Angular repository`](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30835) as well. You can fix it by

Changing the property "target" in the file **`"tsconfig.json"`** to **`"es5"`**.

Comment: It works as expected in `IIS` but in `Azure Static WebSite`. Let me try your solution.

Comment: @andleer after doing this too?

Comment: Your solution resolved my issue. But my issues existed with both angular 8 and 9.

Comment: I have same issue and very confuse.